# Data Annotation with Expressive Conditional Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using Expressive to implement Client side validation,
following is the code, I am using conditional validation, moreover one field is dependent on other

```
[Required(ErrorMessage ="Role Required")]
        public string Role { get; set; }

[RequiredIf("Role == '1'", ErrorMessage = "If you plan to travel abroad, why visit the same country twice?")]
public int ProjectID { get; set; }
```

If role is 1 only then Project Id is compulsory, both are drop down, the issue is that the RequiredIf is not working, I get the validation message saying ProjectId is required, which is not the message that I have initialized it with, it should show me "If you plan to travel abroad, why visit the same"

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this same issue in my own code. You're declaring `ProjectID` as an `int`, which automatically gets a `[Required()]` annotation connected to it invisibly, since a type of `int` cannot be null.

If you change `public int ProjectID` to `public Nullable<int> ProjectID` or 'public int? ProjectID`, that should solve the issue.